# How to skip optional arguments in python, and call *args directly

Tags: python, arguments, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I'm creating a very basic match-market solution that would be used in betting shops. I have a function that looks like this:

```
def create_market(name, match, providerID=str(uuid.uuid4()), market_kind=4, *market_parameters):
```

I want to call a function with only `name`, `match` and `market_parameters` while skipping the `providerID`, and `market_kind` (since these are optional)

Keep in mind that `*market_parameters` will be a tuple of dicts that will be sent inside the function. I unpack it like:

```
for idx, data in enumerate(args):
    for k, v in data.iteritems():
        if 'nWays' in k:
            set_value = v
```

When I set this dict like

```
market_parameters = {'nWays' : 5}
```

and call a function like `create_market('Standard', 1, *market_parameters)`

I can't seem to get the data inside the function body.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"`*market_parameters` will be a dict"* - tuple, for positional parameters; `**kwargs` would be the dictionary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, that's correct :) I was about to write that *market_parameters will be an unknown number of dicts that would be passed as a list (tuple) into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By unpacking it like `*market_parameters`, you send unpacked values as a `providerID` (if you have more values in your dictionary then as `providerID`, `market_kind` and so on).

You probably need

```
def create_market(name, match, *market_parameters,
                  providerID=str(uuid.uuid4()), market_kind=4):
```

and call function like:

```
create_market('Standard', 1, market_parameters) # you don't need to unpack it.
```

and if you want to set `providerID` or `market_kind` then:

```
create_market('Standard', 1, market_parameters, providerID=your_provider_id, market_kind=your_market_kind)
```

Comment: Yes. That's it. Thank you @Yevhen Kuzmovych. You're a life saver.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard I am not sure what you are trying to do but [kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) can be useful.